# Python: How can i compare a User-Input-String in an if-Statement?

Tags: python, string, if-statement, console-application

i know this question may sound stupid, but i´m having problems to check/compare Strings in an if-Statement.

I´m new to Python and we need to make a little project for our school work in python. I decided to do "Rock, Paper, Scissors" as an Console Application.

The Problem i am facing, is that i can´t really compare the User-Input with strings in an if-Statement. I already tried different versions for ex.

```
Benutzerwahl = input("Wähle aus: Schere, Stein, Papier:")
if not Benutzerwahl == "Schere" or Benutzerwahl == "Stein" or Benutzerwahl == "Papier":
    print ("\n")
    print ("Wrong Input, please type in again!")
    print ("\n")
    continue
```

But when i execute the Program and type in for ex. "Papier" (engl. paper) it goes in the if-Statement for some reason, also for every other word i type in.

Am i missing something or what is the Problem?

Here is the whole Code:

```
while (1<2):
    Benutzerwahl = input("Wähle aus: Schere, Stein, Papier:")
    if Benutzerwahl != "Schere" or Benutzerwahl != "Stein" or Benutzerwahl != "Papier":
        print ("\n")
        print ("Falsche Eingabe, bitte richtig eintragen")
        print ("\n")
        continue

    print ('Du hast gewählt: ') + Benutzerwahl
    Wahloptionen = ['Schere', 'Stein', 'Papier']
    GegnerWahl = random.choice(Wahloptionen)
    print ('Ich habe gewählt: ') + GegnerWahl

    if GegnerWahl == Benutzerwahl:
        print ('Unentschieden')
    elif GegnerWahl == 'Schere' and Benutzerwahl == 'Papier':
        print('Schere schneidet Papier! Ich habe gewonnen!')
        continue
    elif GegnerWahl == 'Stein' and Benutzerwahl == 'Schere':
        print('Stein schlägt Schere! Ich habe gewonnen!')
        continue
    elif GegnerWahl == 'Papier' and Benutzerwahl == 'Stein':
        print('Papier schlägt Stein! Ich habe gewonnen')
        continue
    else:
        print('Du hast gewonnen!')
```

Comment: You are using the wrong logic. `x != a or x != b` is *always* true (if `a` and `b` are different).

Comment: `if Benutzerwahl not in {"Schere", "Stein", "Papier"}:` and `while (1<2):` could be a simple `while True:`.

Comment: Check out *De Morgan's laws*.

Comment: Suppose `Benutzerwahl == "Schere"` is `True`. Then `Benutzerwahl != "Stein"` is `True`. And so the whole expression is `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is always `true`, because only one of the inequalities can be `false` at the same time.
So `false or true or true => true`.

You should use `and` instead of `or`.

Even better, you could check whether the input is part of a set:

```
if Benutzerwahl not in {"Schere", "Stein", "Papier"}:
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you TimeTravelingTurtle. This also works and it looks even better than my code before. And also the explanation is quite useful. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

use "and" instead of "or"
"or" will be true as long as one of your checks is true

Comment: Thank you Jackboxx, that was the problem, i´t was really stupid from me. I now replaced the or with the and, and now it works perfectly. Thank you :)